# Profiling start time for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

I want to know how much time is taken by Ubuntu 14.04 when we start it. So for this I have added the below line in `rc.local`

```
awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"($1%60)}' /proc/uptime > /var/log/uptime.log
```

It is showing about 28 seconds. Can someone let me know how can I get more information about what steps are adding to this 28 seconds?